# how to query by sum in ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to build some kind of KPI into my site, and struggling on how to retrive the data. 
for example, let's say I'm building a blog with a model of :

```
class MyPost(ndb.Model):
    Author = ndb.KeyProperty(MyUser, required = True)
    when = TZDateTimeProperty(required = True)
    status = ndb.IntegerProperty(default = 1) # 1=draft, 2=published
    text = ndb.TextProperty()
```

and I want to build a query that would list my top authors that would give me a result of (preferably sorted)

```
['Jack':10, 'Jane':8, 'Joe',0]
```

I can think of 2 ways:

- query().fetch() all items and manually count then
  this is very un-efficient but most flexible
- for author in Users: result[author]=query(...).fetch().count()
  so-so efficiency, and requires to know my indexes in advance (would not work if I want to query by "author's favorit pet"

which one is preferable ?

what other methods would you recommend ?

Comment: Keep a running total in the MyUser entity for each post created. Then you don't have to count anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend de-normalizing the `MyUser` model, that is, introducing redundancy, by giving `MyUser` an `IntegerProperty`, say `numposts`, that redundantly keeps track of how many `MyPost` entities that user has authored.  The need to de-normalize is frequent in NoSQL data stores.

The price you pay for this modest de-normalization is that adding a new post requires more work, since you also need to increment the author's `numposts` when that happens.  However, more often than not, a data store is "read mostly" -- addition of new entities is comparatively rare compared to querying existing ones.  The purpose of de-normalization is to make the latter activity vastly more efficient, for important queries, at a modest cost to the former activity.

Comment: Of course you're right about this. But how can I make it time sensitive? Since this is used for KPI, I want only recent activity. For example: posts written in last 30 days (or future actions, like appointments set to upcoming week in a calendar application)

Comment: @idoroseman, you can do that by updating such "time sensitive" denormalized attributes "in batch" in a cron job executing periodically.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.. Since in that cron job I go back to my initial queries (although in a smaller dataset)